# Спецификация AVI файлов

Tags: c#, видео, спецификация, avi

Есть ли нормальная спецификация формата файлов AVI?

Желательно документированная, т.к. все что мне удалось найти, это некоторые огрызки на сайте майкрософт. А так же не совсем понятный файл, документации в котором явно указано, [что это не официальная документация](http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf).

Все что мне удалось понять, это то что существует заголовок `RIFF`, который в себе содержит в хаотичном порядке заголовки `LIST`, `CHUNK`, `AVIMAIN`,и еще несколько.

Из-за отсутствия документации, я так и не смог понять, как можно унифицировать `LIST` заголовки, т.к. они могу в себя включать как вложенные `LIST`, `CHUNK`, и т.д.

Из-за нехватки информации, мне удается считать только `RIFF` и `AVIMAIN`

Определенный класс `Riff`, структура `AviMain`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 4, Pack = 1)]
public struct FourCc
{
    public uint Value { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value != 0 ? Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Value)) : string.Empty;
    }

    public static implicit operator FourCc(uint value)
    {
        return new FourCc
        {
            Value = value
        };
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 16)]
public struct Reserved
{
    public uint Reserved0 { get; set; }
    public uint Reserved1 { get; set; }
    public uint Reserved2 { get; set; }
    public uint Reserved3 { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct AviMain
{
    public FourCc Type { get; set; }
    public uint Size { get; set; }
    public uint MicroSecPerFrame { get; set; }
    public uint MaxBytesPerSec { get; set; }
    public uint PaddingGranularity { get; set; }
    public uint Flags { get; set; }
    public uint TotalFrames { get; set; }
    public uint InitialFrames { get; set; }
    public uint Streams { get; set; }
    public uint SuggestedBufferSize { get; set; }
    public uint Width { get; set; }
    public uint Height { get; set; }
    public Reserved Reserved { get; set; }
}

public class AviList
{
    public FourCc Type { get; set; }

    public uint Size { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public T As<T>() where T : unmanaged
    {
        unsafe
        {
            byte[] bytes = Data;
            fixed (void* tPtr = bytes)
            {
                return *(T*) tPtr;
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct AviChunk
{
}

public class Riff
{
    public FourCc Fcc { get; set; }
    public uint FileSize { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrectSize { get; set; }
    public FourCc FileType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AviList> AviLists { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и небольшой, не доделанный `Stream`:

```
public sealed class AviFileStream : BinaryReader
{
    public AviFileStream(Stream input) : base(input, Encoding.ASCII)
    {
        FourCc fourCcValue = ReadUInt32();
        uint fileSize = ReadUInt32();
        FourCc fileType = ReadUInt32();
        FourCc listOrChunk = ReadUInt32();

        bool isList = string.Equals(listOrChunk.ToString(), "LIST", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        List<AviList> aviLists = new List<AviList>();

        Riff riff = new Riff
        {
            Fcc = fourCcValue,
            FileSize = fileSize,
            IsCorrectSize = BaseStream.Length - fileSize == 8,
            FileType = fileType
        };

        if (isList)
        {
            uint listSize = ReadUInt32();

            unsafe
            {
                int readBytes = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[listSize];
                Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                fixed (byte* bytesPtr = bytes)
                {
                    while (readBytes < listSize)
                    {
                        uint* dataPtr = (uint*) bytesPtr + readBytes;
                        AviList list = new AviList
                        {
                            Type = *dataPtr,
                            Size = *(dataPtr + 2)
                        };

                        ArraySegment<byte> dataSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 4, (int)list.Size);
                        byte[] dataBytes = dataSegment.ToArray();
                        list.Data = dataBytes;
                        readBytes += dataBytes.Length + 2;
                        aviLists.Add(list);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        riff.AviLists = aviLists;
        Riff = riff;

        BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    public Riff Riff { get; }
}
```

Дело в том, что при получении размера списка `uint listSize = ReadUInt32();`, я получаю размер, около 8 КБ, далее читаю это кол-во байт, и пытаюсь вычитать список в цикле, однако, `AviMain` считывается, но далее, либо идет какой-то мусор, либо я чего-то не до понял.

Если посмотреть на [эту страницу](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/dv-data-in-the-avi-file-format), то там вообще показано, что список идет список в списке, и какаим образом определить что идет список в списке, мне не понятно.

Comment: Мне загуглилось только [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/avi-riff-file-reference)

Comment: @tym32167, Да, я оттуда информацию брал, но там ничего почти нет, и некоторые ссылки вообще битые.

Comment: Через [статью на вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) можно выйти на [эту ссылку](https://web.archive.org/web/20170411001412/http://www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf). А вообще я бы на вашем месте посмотрел исходники какого-нибудь опенсорсного видеоредактора, например VirtualDubMod. Он правда не на c#, но, думаю, при желании можно разобраться.